# Monty Hall variant with sequential decision making

Tags: probability, game-theory, monty-hall

There are $n$ doors, only one has a prize behind it. You can pick one at the beginning. At every round, host will open a door (which is empty) and ask you if you want to switch. The game will last $n-2$ rounds.

I think the optimal strategy is to stay put till the last turn and then switch but it is hard to prove.

At first I think there is a simple recurrence relation:

if the current door contains prize with probability $p$, and there are $m$ closed doors . After switching, the probability becomes $\frac{1-p}{m-1}$.

However, I realized that player can always switch back to a previously chosen door if it is not being opened yet. So the probability will depend on your decision (chose a new door or switch back to previously chosen doors) and also the strategy of the host (for example, a mixed strategy where host has probability $q$ of opening the door player just left and $1-q$ of opening a random empty door).

Can anyone give me an idea of this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, how many rounds are there?  Do you know in advance?  If so, then...yes.  By switching early you substitute a low probability door for a high one, and thus risk that he'll open the one you left behind and you'll get less information than you otherwise would.

Comment: @lulu, there are $n-2$ rounds. Your reasoning is right, but player can always switch back to his original choice hence revert the probability, and if host always open the door player just left, it will leak the information of the prize location.

Comment: That does not change the reasoning.  As there will be two doors at the end, your goal is to ensure that one of these has as high a probability as possible.  Equivalently, you want the other to have as low a probability as possible.  At every round, every door that isn't opened (other than yours) goes up in probability...therefore your best option is to keep your $\frac 1n$ door and ultimately swap it for the $\frac {n-1}n$ door.

Comment: I am phrasing the argument informally, but it is easy enough to make it formal.  Say that at some round (prior to the end) you abandon your $\frac 1n$ door.  Then either our man opens the one you left behind (and thereby kills the only remaining $\frac 1n$ door) or he opens another, in which case the probability of the $\frac 1n$ door goes up.  Either way, because you switched you ensured that every door will have probability greater than $\frac 1n$, so switching is sub-optimal.

Comment: A simpler way to see it:  nothing in the game ever allows a surviving door's probability to go down.  Your door retains its probability and every other surviving door goes up.  Therefore nothing you do can ever achieve an available door with probability less than $\frac 1n$ so no strategy can outperform staying with yours until the last round.

Comment: @lulu, wow, is there a way to calculate how the probability is updated?

Comment: Of course.  At any round, the probability attached to the opened door is distributed uniformly to the doors our man chose not to open.  That's easy to calculate if you stick with yours, but if you switch then you have to keep track of the full list of remaining probabilities so it gets messier.

Comment: I am assuming, as I think we must, that Monty chooses uniformly amongst the doors he can open.  If, to the contrary, he has rules he must follow then it is possible that those rules will let you make more precise deductions.

Comment: Correction:  I do not believe my simple analysis anymore, sorry.  In particular, my simple distribution rule fails if the options have different probabilities. More to the point, to my surprise, it is possible to lower a probability.  Say you have three doors with $p_1=.2,p_2=.3,p_3=.5$.  You choose $\#1$ and Monty opens $\#2$.  Then your revised estimate for $p_1$ is $\frac 16$.  My apologies for the error.

Comment: In general, I think that one redistributes according to Bayes' theorem.  That's easy enough to calculate with, but I find it harder than expected to have intuition for the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Monty is required to open all unpicked bad doors, when he opens a bad door to open, you know that he chose it because it is not your pick and it is not the prize. That is the information you gain. For each of the doors that you have not picked, this tells you that the pool they were in has gotten smaller, so their probability has gotten larger. But your door is not in that pool. Monty didn't pick it because it was your current choice. you gain no new information about it, so its probability does not change. No door ever goes down in probability. It will either go up, or if it is your choice, it will stay the same.

As long as you keep it, your inital door has probability $\frac 1n$. The probability of all the other doors rose from that to $\frac 1{n-1}$ at the first reveal. If you have any other door at the final swap, its probability will be at least $\frac 1{n-1}$, since the door can never go down in probability. If at some time you leave your initial door, then while you are holding another door, your initial door also goes up in probability. If you switch back, its probability will still be greater than $\frac 1n$.

You could maximize the probability of your door at the final swap by picking a new never-chosen door each time. But it will never have probability $>\frac 12$, so you are always wisest to swap at the final opportunity. Thus your best strategy is to minimize the probability of your door at this time, thereby maximizing the probability of the other door.

Therefore, your best strategy is to stick with your original door until the last opportunity, maintaining its original $\frac 1n$ probability as the prize door, then switch.